# Accessing Data on Remote Server without Setting Data Sources everytime?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers

I'm in one of two offices within my company. The other office has a large library of GIS maps they've created on a drive they've named the M:\ drive. Of course, when I open the maps all of the links are broken since they're referencing data on their server, and not mine. As it stands I use the "Repair Data Source" feature and navigate to the folders, but it's often excruciatingly slow.

I'd like to open their maps without any broken links. I've mapped the drive through Windows, and used Catalog to create a folder connection, but obviously neither have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are able to mimic the folder location from the original system in yours, which would be an IT rather than GIS solution, I think the best option would be to use ArcPy to visit (arcpy.da.Walk) and replaceDataSource in all your map documents and layer files.

If you do not find existing code to do this then there are many Q&As on this site from which to choose some code to use as a starting point.

Comment: I'd vote twice for naming the local library drive `M:`, since it's an actual solution, vice the kludge of repairing map documents endlessly.